# Tangent bundle of $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am trying to show that $T\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $\text{Hom}(\gamma_1,\gamma_1^{\perp})$ are isomorphic bundles over $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

For $[x]\in\mathbb{RP}^n$, let $L_x$ be the line in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ joining the two representatives $x$ and $-x$ of $[x]$ and let $L_x^{\perp}$ be its orthogonal complement in $\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Given $(x,v)\in T\mathbb{RP}^n$ we have a linear transformation $T(x,v):L_x\rightarrow L_x^{\perp}$ defined by $T(x,v)(x)=v$. This is clearly well defined because $T(x,v)(-x)=-v$. Now, for each $[x]\in\mathbb{RP}^n$ we have an isomorphism on each fiber $T(x,*): T_{[x]}\mathbb{RP}^n \rightarrow \text{Hom}(L_x,L_x^{\perp})$ given by $T(x,*): (x,v) \mapsto T(x,v)$. However, finding an isomorphism for each fiber is not enough, how can I show these fiber isomorphisms actually induce a homeomorphism of the total spaces of $T\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $\text{Hom}(\gamma_1,\gamma_1^{\perp})$?

Comment: Sorry, what's $\gamma_1$?

Comment: $\gamma_1$ is the line bundle of over $\mathbb{RP}^n$, that is $\gamma_1=\{([x],v): [x]\in \mathbb{RP}^n, v\in [x]\}$.

Comment: Ah, it's $\mathscr{O}(-1)$. Thanks!

Comment: Oh well, I guess if a continuous map between total spaces is an isomorphism on each fiber then it is a homeomorphism... we could restrict to a local trivialization and construct an inverse there?

Comment: You should be more explicit about how you are viewing the tangent space.  Your map make it seem like you are already identifying $\gamma^{\perp}$ and $T\mathbb{RP}^n$.  If $q:S^n\to \mathbb{RP}^n$ is the quotient map, you have that $q^*\gamma^{\perp}\cong q^* T\mathbb{RP}^n \cong TS^n$ and $q^* \gamma$ is the trivial bundle, but you need to be careful to do something which explains why you need to take the hom (because that reason disappears after you pull back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is correct. You need to use the following lemma

(Milnor-Stasheff 2.3): Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be vector bundles over $B$, and let $f:E(\xi) \to E(\eta)$ be a continuous function which maps each vector space $F_b(\xi)$ isomorphically onto $F_b(\eta)$. Then $f$ is necessarily a homeomorphism. Hence $\xi$ is isomorphic to $\eta$

The proof is, as you would expect, to think locally! (Let me know if you want me to put the proof up)

Comment: This is also Lemma 1.1 [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf)

Comment: That's good. I should have thought a bit more before posting the question... Thanks!

Comment: How can we show the continuity of the corresponding map of total spaces?@Manuel